# Getting length 0 even though there is data in vue

Tags: laravel, vue.js

I'm trying to create a vue app, but when I try to pass some data to another vue page I get length 0 even though there is data that I'm receiving from my axios.get() function. I'm not even getting any errors that I can see.

Here is my code

my users.js

```
    Vue.component('users-app', require('./UsersApp.vue').default);
    Vue.component('users-table', require('./UsersTable.vue').default);

    if (document.getElementById('users')) {
        const blockRequest = new Vue({
            el: "#users",
            data() {
                return {
                    users: []
                }
            },
            methods: {
                getUsers(){
                    axios.get('/users/get-users').then(response => {
                        this.users = response.data.users;
                    });
                }
            },
            mounted() {
                this.getUsers();
            }
        });
    }
```

This is my users.blade.php

```
    @section('content')
        <div class="row justify-content-center">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <div id="users">
                    <users-app :users="users"></users-app>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    @endsection
```

My UsersApp,vue

```
    <template>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-6">
                
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6">
            
            </div>
        </div>
    </template>

    <script>
        export default {
            props: ['users'],
            data() {
                return {
                  
                }
            },
            methods: {

            },
            mounted() {
                console.log(this.users);
            }
        }
    </script>
```

Comment: where this that code your getting `length` 0 .?

Comment: You're fetching your users using axios which is async. So you're probably accessing `this.users` before they're done being fetched.

Answer (score 0):

Try and use this.$set(this, 'users', response.data.users) in your method. Not sure you bind it correctly.